# Databricks: autoloader and multiple files with differing schema?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, databricks-autoloader

I'm following the Databricks Cloud tutorial.  I see sample data located at DBFS:

```
/databricks-datasets/structured-streaming/events
dbfs:/databricks-datasets/structured-streaming/events/file-0.json
dbfs:/databricks-datasets/structured-streaming/events/file-1.json
```

It looks like these JSON files have the same schema.  What happens using `spark.readStream.load(path)` if above files have different schema?  Should they typically have the same schema?

Comment: The docs explain what happens. https://docs.databricks.com/en/ingestion/auto-loader/schema.html#how-does-auto-loader-schema-evolution-work